# What are the possible causes of BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE?

Tags: android, androidx, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I found this definition from the code

```
/**
 * The user can't authenticate because the hardware is unavailable. Try again later.
 */
public static final int BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE = 1;
```

Since there's already `BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE` for the case where the device has no hardware and the definition of `BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE` has "try again later", it looks like `BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE` means the hardware is there. It's just not available at the moment. If that's the case, what are the possible causes for this?

Answer (score 0):

You may have disabled the Hardware at OS level using certain techniques(like how we disable the hardware/devices on Windows's Device manager). or the hardware may have not functioning correctly or corrupted (but Exists). in such cases, BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE is thrown so that user can get it corrected/repaired/fixed.